# Running ClojureScript: Unable to locate cljs/main.clj

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Total rookie here. I am trying to run `ClojureScript` for the first time and followed [the quickstart tutorial](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start). However, upon entering...

```
clj --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl
```

I get the following error message:

```
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at clojure.main/main (main.java:40).
FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cljs/main__init.class or cljs/main.clj on classpath.
```

Comment: You need to specify which platform, it's different between windows and *nix.

Comment: I had the same issue, I had a deps file with the clojurescript dependency. The reason it didn't work for me is I was running the clj command in the src directory. I switched to the directory containing the deps file and it worked instantly.

Comment: @nakamin Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

It can’t find the cljs.main in the Clojurescript jar. As the QuickStart mentions, you need a deps.edn for Mac/Linux or the cljs.jar for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> Make sure you are in the hello-world project directory and run the following command....

Docs are wrong, run the command on the root where `deps.edn` exist

Answer (score 1):

This error surfaces when one runs `clj --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl` from directory or path which does not have file `deps.end` or `cljs.jar`.

Considering the directory structure at https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start,

```
hello-world  #### Run that command in this directory
├─ src   
│  └─ hello_world
│     └─ core.cljs 
├─ cljs.jar 
└─ deps.edn
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific error, but I created a CLJS sample project that will get you started:

https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-base-project

Just clone the repo to your computer, then you can run the Doo unit tests:

```
> lein clean; lein doo chrome test once
```

or use Figwheel:

```
> lein clean; lein figwheel
```

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me in a Linux box, even though I had the correct `deps.edn` as mentioned in the quickstart.

The solution was to simply remove a previously created `.cpcache` folder that I had from trying with a different docker image.